# How to remove Gmail's prevention of the “suspicious sign-in”?

Tags: gmail, security

I got mail from Gmail saying someone from a certain IP tried to log-in and it was prevented and that I should reset my password by following the given link if I don't recognise the address.

> ...We prevented the sign-in attempt in case this was a hijacker trying to access your account...

However, this is not from a hijacker but from an application I set up some time ago. Now it can not access my account. How can I remove the prevention of the sign-in?

Comment: Why can't you access your account? What's the problem?

Comment: If it’s an app, how about enabling the _application-specific password_ feature?

Comment: I also have a problem, but the option of "allow access to less secured application" is sisable due google suspected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use Google's [Unlock Catpcha](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha) to unblock your application. I can't find much official doco on it, but according to [this post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/gmail/8HeF3DAcCUE) if you unlock with the captcha logins for the next ten minutes are recognised as legitimate.

Comment: In fact, I do NOT have full authorization of the application, which, in my case, is sipsorcery. I just checked my sipsorcery account, and it turns out that my google account was set up as sip provider in sipsorcery. However, sipsorcery failed to register into google account, and I guess that google has prevented it to sign in. Any one has a solution for it?

Comment: It appears Unlock Catpcha does work in my case.  https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78754

Comment: @John, Doesn't doco mean documentary instead of documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Go into the the message and then, on the bottom right hand corner there should be a button that says details. Click that then choose 'Never show an alert for unusual activity' Then after 7 days it should stop sending you them alerts, in 7 days because they want to make sure that the 'bad guys' did not choose that. Then from then on you shouldn't be getting any more annoying alerts.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably an old question, but I think Google has updated it now. You only need to turn on "Allow less secure apps" in your settings.

The most easy way is to click "Review your devices" in the email: when you are asked if you did the sign-in attempt, click "Yes, that was me" and "OK". Then you are given the chance to "Allow less secure apps" (though they don't recommend it)

Look carefully because the link "Allow less secure apps" is pretty small.

Comment: This support page details how to reach the "Allow less secure apps" page: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en The link they refer to at this time is http://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: As of 2021, google will block applications as "suspicious sign-in attempts" even if "allow less secure apps" is enabled. As far as I can tell users no longer have control over this.